# SATA and USB boot

Tags: boot, usb, backup

So I cloned my Hard Drive (my usual backup method) using Todo backup and then disconnected source drive and then booted from clone and all was great.I want also to run the clone if necessary using a USB converter and the booting hung up at the blue window. (the source drive disconnected to mimic HD crash) Ran the clone drive again with SATA cables and all OK again.
I have a linux mint drive in another USB converter attachment and it runs fine after I change the boot order.

Comment: You may want to edit your post so that your question is more clear. It is difficult to tell what exactly you are asking

Comment: Basic question is what is keeping a HDD created with SATA attachment from working as a USB drive.?

Comment: Windows can't run from external drives, Linux can.

Comment: Please Edit the question rather than responding in Comments.  Think of how the question is read in the future, so that you can help the next guy with the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has a Windows-To-Go feature that offers a form of running from USB, but only for Enterprise and Education versions of Windows 8 and 10.

However, the root problem in your case is that, as @GabrielaGarcia notes, Windows does not support running the full Windows experience from USB.